# Is the display of the Asus Zenbook UX301 covered with Gorilla Glass?

Tags: asus-laptop, specifications, ultrabook, zenbook

I hope it's ok to ask this question here, I could not find a better site in the StackExchange universe.

I cannot find information about whether the display of the Asus Zenbook UX301 is covered with Corning Gorilla Glass 3. Everywhere (asus website, and everywhere else I found information about this ultrabook) the statements are very nice said, but are not precise. Like..

```
The all-new ZENBOOK™ UX301 Ultrabook™ transforms your perception of beauty with a     
Corning® Gorilla® Glass 3 lid that is visually stunning, 3x tougher, and more damage 
resistant than its predecessors.
```

And then...

```
First Ultrabook™ protected by Corning Gorilla Glass 3 - delivers durability and scratch-
resistance while looking stunning as ever
```

and...

```
Exceptional design meets superior craftsmanship and perfect details. Scratch-resistant 
Corning® Gorilla® Glass design means never having to worry about scratches or dents.
```

But I could not find a single place which would state that the display itself is covered with Gorilla Glass. I am not an expert to tell by touching the display if it's some "kind of glass" or Gorilla Glass. 
I ask this question because I am confused I don't find this information in any official statement, as I would expect Asus to tell it straight forward that the display is scratch resistant, but Asus does not. Gorilla Glass is never mentioned in sections about the display, it's always mentioned with design and overall information. Is this a perfect marketing trick or am I paranoid?

Comment: All 3 statements are pretty clear.  The display is protected by `Gorilla Glass`.  **First Ultrabook™ protected by Corning Gorilla Glass 3** this is crystal clear.

Comment: They were if the top of the lid was not covered by Gorilla Glass. The top of the lid is covered, that is for 100% sure. Why does it say "Glass lid" , "Glass design", "Ultrabook protected by", but every detail description about the display does not name GG once.

Comment: Except...The top of the lid isn't made out of glass.

Comment: The top of the lid is Gorilla Glass covered: www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Ib-D2L0NWY

Comment: I stand corrected that means the monitor isn't protected but the case is.

Comment: Do you have any source? I have just sent an e-mail to ASUS support, let's see what they will tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally got the reply from the German ASUS Tech support. The reply was short and concise:

> nein der Bildschirm wird nicht mit Gorilla Glas 3 geschützt.

Which means - no, the display is not protected by Gorilla Glas.